# Typescript assign type to an object from a type within another type

Tags: typescript, typescript3.0

I've got a type like this:

```
export function reorderPiece(contentId:string, id:string, otherId:string){
  return {
    type: REORDER_PIECE_PENDING,
    payload: {id, otherId, contentId}
  }
}
```

This action goes through a pipeline (that I can't refactor at this point) and in another function I need to assign *type of payload* to an object.

I can get return type of `reorderPiece` easily:

`x:ReturnType<typeof reorderPiece>` and access `x.payload`. But how do I assign type of payload (which is `{id:string, otherId:string, contentId:string}` automatically by picking that type from the type `ReturnType<typeof reorderPiece>` so that `x` is something like `typeof ReturnType<typeof reorderPiece>.payload` so that `x` will have the type `{id:string, otherId:string, contentId:string}` and I can access it as `x.id` or `x.contentId`?

I know I can always write such type explicitly (or implicitly) and use that type in my method, but I'm wondering if it's possible to pick that type from method automatically.

(I'm on Typescript 3.7.5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [lookup](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) type:

> Syntactically, they look exactly like an element access, but are written as types

```
declare const x: ReturnType<typeof reorderPiece>['payload'];
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVysaAE2CgAVNg1gAKNHGYFGASUIC4BnGKTFAcwA0cTOy49+QiDAAWJVp268+ASgDeAKDh5gMJFFwatWmAE8wwNnADkAJQCiAeRsAROzYD6pZnYDCdz3YAcs7MgQDiVgKaRmAAhiYANhCx7HCqIpIycoRCdEyMLIQAvtElJerEaAmx+HB5XHAgljY6eigAKmbAADym5hAI2kQk5JTAAHwA2lZxicmEVgC6ANxwAPRracKpYkqrUrJQ8nC7-Kt5DEzHp3yrRUA)

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Thanks!